# AMP subset of HTML, or extended subset? amp-img in HTML

Tags: amp-html

I'm new to AMP, and keep reading that it's a subset of HTML. However, it has tags that HTML does not, such as `amp-img`. So, I believe the proper term would be extended subset.

For example, if I include the tag `amp-img` in my AMP, it won't render at all in an HTML-only browser.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is a subset in the sense that only the whitelisted HTML5 tags are allowed:

```
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-tag-addendum.md
```

Also, AMP comes with a set of components, such as amp-img, which provides most of the functionality (otherwise requiring Javascripting) for publishing.

So I would call it a subset with the addition of pre-defined (web) components — my 2 cents.